# Intent doesn't redirect to an other activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity "Data" and "OpenedClass" when i create an Intent to redirect me to an other activity it doesn't work

Data activity

```
package com.example.androidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText sendET;
    Button start,startFor;
    TextView gotAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        sendET= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
        startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAFR);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
        gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGot);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        startFor.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSA:

            String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
            Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putString("key", bread);
            Intent a = new Intent(Data.this,OpenedClass.class);
            a.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(a);

            break;
        case R.id.bSAFR:

            break;


        }

    }

}
```

And Opened Class Activity

```
package com.example.androidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OpenedClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener , OnCheckedChangeListener {

    TextView question , test;
    Button returnData;
    RadioGroup selection;
    String gotBread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);
        initialize();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        gotBread = b.getString("key");
        question.setText(gotBread);

    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        question= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        returnData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
        selection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgAnswers);
        returnData.setOnClickListener(this);
        selection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.rCrazy:

            break;

        case R.id.rSerious:

            break;

        case R.id.rBoth:

            break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

here is the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".OpenedClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

the button doesn't redirect me to the second activity , help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `initialize` method after `setContentView` on your `Data Activity`, so the `Listener's` are not being registered on `Button's`. Like:

```
public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText sendET;
    Button start,startFor;
    TextView gotAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);

        initialize();
    }

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your `Data` Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, OpenedClass.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtras(basket);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Where `mContext` is defined in your `Data` Activity as:

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    initialize();
    // Other codes here.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your Data Activity,your initialize() did not call.